# Control custrom script through discord.py bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio

As title says, I have a script, that is doing (some super secret) task, which is running almost non-stop.
What I do now, is to check it every now and then, to see if its running smoothly.

I have switched from python2.7 to python 3.7 recently and with that, I started to play with discord.py bot little bit. Now, what I want to do, is to make my script, that is running almost non-stop to:

1. Print its log into discord server, so I can check if its running smoothly without the need to get to PC
2. Be able to control the script through discord commands

So, basically, there are 2 things I want to achieve:

1.) When the script prints some log into console, send it also to discord.py bot which will send it to given channel

2.) Make discord.py bot to read given channel (different than previous one) and if the correct command comes, take action in the script (do something, or just change some variable value)

Here is my code example I have so far:

```
# Discord bot, to control bot over discord
try:
    import discord
    import disc_bot_con
    from discord.ext import commands
except Exception as x:
    print("Unable to import discord libraries [%s]" % x)


# Global methods *******************************************************************************************************
def print_log(msg, lvl=None):
    if lvl == 'i':
        print("[%s] INFO:       %s" % (datetime.datetime.now(), msg))
    elif lvl == 'w':
        print("[%s] WARNING:    %s" % (datetime.datetime.now(), msg))
    elif lvl == 'e':
        print("[%s] ERRROR:     %s" % (datetime.datetime.now(), msg))
    elif lvl == 'd':
        if DEBUG:
            print("[%s] DEBUG:      %s" % (datetime.datetime.now(), msg))
    else:
        print("[%s] %s" % (datetime.datetime.now(), msg))


# Classes **************************************************************************************************************
class Script:
    def __init__(self):
        # do soemthing

    def run(self):
        # repeatedly doing some stuff
        while True:
            if something:
                print_log('Soemthing')
            else:
                print_log('Taking action')
                self.take_action()


class ScriptDiscordBot(discord.Client):
    async def setup_guild(self):
        await self.login(disc_bot_con.TOKEN)
        self.guild = discord.utils.get(self.guilds, name=disc_bot_con.NAME_CZ_SK_RIVALS)
        self.channel = discord.utils.get(self.guild.channels, name='bot_trash')

    async def my_background_task(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        counter = 0
        channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
        while not self.is_closed:
            counter += 1
            await self.send_message(channel, counter)
            await asyncio.sleep(60)  # task runs every 60 seconds

    async def on_connect(self):
        print_log("Connecting to discord!")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        guild = discord.utils.get(self.guilds, name=disc_bot_con.NAME_CZ_SK_RIVALS)
        print('Logged to: {0}!'.format(self.guild))

    async def send_log(self, message):
        #channel = discord.utils.get(self.guild.channels, name=chanel_name)
        channel_id = self.channel.id
        await self.send_message(channel_id, message)


# run the thing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not TEST_MODE:
        try:
            opts, extraparams = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'ASFWsc:t:w:h', ['help'])
        except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            print(str(err))
            Script.print_help()
            sys.exit(2)

        discord_bot = ScriptDiscordBot()
        discord_bot.run(disc_bot_con.TOKEN)

        the_bot = Script()
        the_bot.run()
```

When I run it like this, it starts bot and running it, but does not start the Script class, obviously.

At first, I have been trying to encapsulate `ScriptDiscordBot` into separate thread..but it did not worked.

```
# run the thing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not TEST_MODE:
        try:
            opts, extraparams = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'ASFWsc:t:w:h', ['help'])
        except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            print(str(err))
            Script.print_help()
            sys.exit(2)

        discord_bot = ScriptDiscordBot()
        t = threading.Thread(target=discord_bot.run, args=disc_bot_con.TOKEN)
        t.start()

        the_bot = Script()
        the_bot.run()
```

Than I tried to make discord bot to run in abckground, as github exampel says, but also no luck there.

```
# run the thing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not TEST_MODE:
        try:
            opts, extraparams = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'ASFWsc:t:w:h', ['help'])
        except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            print(str(err))
            Script.print_help()
            sys.exit(2)

        discord_bot = ScriptDiscordBot()
        discord_bot.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
        discord_bot.login(disc_bot_con.TOKEN)

        the_bot = Script()
        the_bot.run()
```

The last thing I have tried was, to not make run discord bot at all, but call its methods from `Script` instead.

```
# run the thing
if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not TEST_MODE:
        try:
            opts, extraparams = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'ASFWsc:t:w:h', ['help'])
        except getopt.GetoptError as err:
            print(str(err))
            Script.print_help()
            sys.exit(2)

        discord_bot = ScriptDiscordBot()
        discord_bot.setup_guild()
        discord_bot.send_log('Test')

        the_bot = Script()
        the_bot.run()
```

Also no luck there. :(

I am familiar with `Threading` and `Multiprocessing` from python2.7 but `asyncio` is completely new for me. I have been trying different approaches, to make it work. I have coded many applications where multiple processes are running at once, but this seems like too much for me to handle. I think its very simple task, but the solution seems impossible for me.

Also, I am pretty sure I am thinking wrong way about it, but I have no idea how should I think here. So Id use little bit of correction in the way I am thinking about it, and also some code examples. The examples in dicsord.py documentation and github are super simple, I have them working in separate script, but I am somehow unable to make those two scripts cooperate, or run at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a task so it's more easy to manage:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def my_background_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something, you can put your script here
```

How to start, cancel, stop, restart a task?

```py
my_background_task.start()
my_background_task.cancel()
my_background_task.stop()
my_background_task.restart(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here are some useful methods/attributes

```py
my_background_task.current_loop
my_background_task.next_iteration
my_background_task.is_running()
my_background_task.is_being_cancelled()
```

You can also do things before/after the task starts with the decorators

```py
@my_background_task.before_loop
async def before_my_background_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something before


@my_background_task.after_loop
async def after_my_background_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something
```

Here's a little example on how to use it with a command

```py
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    my_background_task.start(some_arguments_here)
    await ctx.send('Task started')


@bot.command()
async def edit_task(ctx, *some_parameters_id_to_change):
    my_background_task.restart(some_parameters_id_to_change)
    await ctx.send(f'Task restarted with the following arguments:\n`{some_parameters_id_to_change}`')
```

Here's a brief explanation in how could you do it using `discord.ext.tasks`
If you need anything let me know in the comments ↓

Reference:

- [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.Loop)

Comment: well, I should probably mention, that the `Script` is some 1500+ lines of code class, doing stuff like image recognition, watching timers and taking decisions based on the results :) so it is not really an easy thing to put it into some method.